# Loading bing directions module Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, bing-maps

Using bing maps, at the moment I can create a map add pins and update pins

What I'm trying to do now is create/update routes, but the loadModule function doesn't fire

```
  Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function() {
        //Create an instance of the directions manager.
        this.directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(this.map);

        console.log(this.directionsManager)//This doesn't show

        //Set the request options that uses kilometers.
        this.directionsManager.setRequestOptions({
          distanceUnit: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DistanceUnit.km
        });
        //Make the route line thick and green.
        this.directionsManager.setRenderOptions({
          drivingPolylineOptions: {
            strokeColor: 'green',
            strokeThickness: 6
          }
        });

      });
```

As I say I can do things such as;

```
this.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(...)
```

Or

```
this.user = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the I had to change

```
 Microsoft.Maps.loadModule(..)
```

To

```
 Microsoft.Maps.Module.loadModule(...)
```